# SFML window.clear() not clearing screen?

Tags: c++, sfml

For some strange reason or another the screen is not clearing. I have it set so that after 4 seconds after the levelMainDraw has been drawn then it should clear the screen. For some reason its not. I have set DrawMainMenu to true and levelMainDraw to false, by default at the top of the code.

```
   //Checks if DrawMainMenu is true or false
    if (DrawMainMenu == true) {
        window.draw(mainMenuSprite);
        window.draw(rect);
        window.draw(buttonText);
    }
    else if (DrawMainMenu == false){
        window.clear();
        levelMainDraw = true;
    }
    //checks if levelMainDraw is true or false
    if (levelMainDraw == true)
    {
        window.draw(levelSelectSprite);
        sf::Clock clock;
        sf::Time time = clock.getElapsedTime();

        if (time.asSeconds() >= 4)
        {
            window.clear();
        }
```

Comment: You're measuring the time since the creation of `clock`. That will never be 4 seconds.

Comment: @molbdnilo do you mind posting up what I should do instead?

Comment: Not do that. I don't understand why you want to clear only after 4 seconds. SFML is made to clear every frame in an efficient way. What exactly are you trying to achieve with this clear?

Comment: @Rosme I am making a super mario bros remake as my first game. In the original super mario bros after they person pressed start it would show the level that that they are on, clear the screen and then get into the actual level itself. If i don't set a timer of some sort, then whenever the player clicks start in my game, it won't show the level they are on it will just clear straight away. I dont want it to do that. Here is what I am trying to copy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ia8bhFoqkVE you will see that after he chooses 1 player game the screen shows what level he is on then moves on.

Comment: You might actually want to read on state machines and such and revised your conception at some point. You could have a state machine that draws the level state, and after 4 seconds, change state. The following state is the game. For your problem with the clock, is that you create the clock, and request directly after that the elapsed time. There is no chance that 4 seconds elapsed. And I suppose this is a loop, so everytime, it recreates a new clock. You might want to create the clock outside the loop, if it is. If not, there is not enough info to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new clock each time you check for the time elapsed.

This means that you will never clear your screen, since the clock will "reset" every time you create it.

Actually, the clock from the last cycle no longer exists, and a new one, with timer=0 will be created.

You need to create your clock as a persistent entity in your game if you want to measure the elapsed time.